# Skip explicit selection of package (and force download of the latest)

Tags: apt

I type `sudo apt-get install lua` and I get the following:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package lua is a virtual package provided by:
  lua5.3:i386 5.3.1-1
  lua5.2:i386 5.2.4-1
  lua5.1:i386 5.1.5-8
  lua50 5.0.3-7
  lua5.3 5.3.1-1
  lua5.2 5.2.4-1
  lua5.1 5.1.5-8
You should explicitly select one to install.

E: Package 'lua' has no installation candidate
```

I suppose the authors of the package want you to choose manually the package you want to install.

Isn't there any way to force the direct download of the latest package (in this case 5.3)?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Just copy the text here and apply code formatting.

Comment: @maru: ok, sorry

Comment: What's the problem with `sudo apt-get install lua5.3`? O.ò

Comment: @dadexix86: I have two requirements: 1) a 9 years old boy must use the terminal; 2) he must choose the latest version (when he'll be typing that lua5.3, the latest could not be 5.3 anymore)

Comment: @IanBell Why would you give the many responsibilities that come with `sudo` to a 9 years old? That's just cruel (this is a joke obviously!, but what follows is not)  Anyway, I would assume that a 9 years old with that power *knows* that 6.2>5.4>5.3... It is something that they still teach in primary school, right?

Comment: @dadexix86: you're right. Moreover, the boy will be helped by his dad and/or a school teacher. BUT, I was looking for a way for him to avoid asking for help

Answer (score 1):

With a quick hack:

```
sudo apt-get install \
    $(sudo apt-get install -s lua | \
        awk '/^ +lua/' | \
        cut -d : -f 1 | \
        sort -Vu -k2 | \
        awk 'END {print $1}')
```

or

```
package="lua"
sudo apt-get install \
    $(sudo apt-get install -s "$package" | \
        awk '/^ +'"$package"'/' | \
        cut -d : -f 1 | \
        sort -Vu -k2 | \
        awk 'END {print $1}')
```

---

```
$ sudo apt-get install \
    $(sudo apt-get install -s lua | \
        awk '/^ +lua/' | \
        cut -d : -f 1 | \
        sort -Vu -k2 | \
        awk 'END {print $1}')
E: Package 'lua' has no installation candidate
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  lua5.3
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 103 kB of archives.
After this operation, 379 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily/main lua5.3 amd64 5.3.1-1 [103 kB]
Fetched 103 kB in 0s (215 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package lua5.3.
(Reading database ... 419661 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../lua5.3_5.3.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking lua5.3 (5.3.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.4-1) ...
Setting up lua5.3 (5.3.1-1) ...
```

Comment: Please, could you expand a little?